# IF condition check inside USING method and SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement, sqlconnection, using-statement

I am trying to run data validation, execute some code and pass data from one SQL query to another.

My current code looks like the below:

```
public string SelectUniqueKeyNumber()
{
    string newList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfSkus).ToString();
    string key_id;
    string sqlConnectionString = @"someConnectionString";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 1 KEY_NUMBER from MyTable where QTY_ON_HAND > 0 " + newList + " order by NEWID()", connection);

        SqlDataReader readerKey = command.ExecuteReader();
        readerKey.Read();

        key_id = String.Format(readerKey[0].ToString());
    }

    SelectSkuNumber(key_id);
    return key_id;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to check if my `readerKey.Read()` is not returning `null` value. If it does then stop the process, otherwise continue. I've tried it in the way as shown below:

```
public string SelectUniqueKeyNumber()
{
    string newList = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listOfSkus).ToString();
    string key_id;
    string sqlConnectionString = @"someConnectionString";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select top 1 KEY_NUMBER from MyTable where QTY_ON_HAND > 0 " + newList + " order by NEWID()", connection);

        SqlDataReader readerKey = command.ExecuteReader();
        readerKey.Read();

        if(readerkey.Read().ToString() == null)
        {
            //--- stop processing
        }
        else
        {
            key_id = String.Format(readerKey[0].ToString());
        }
    }

    SelectSkuNumber(key_id); //---> Then ...(key_id) is not declared value
    return key_id;
}
```

By doing so, I cannot access and pass data of `SelectSkuNumber(key_id)` due to: `Use of unassigned local variable 'key_id'`

Any ideas?

Comment: Just initialize `key_id` with null or empty string to get rid of this error. However, this is not the original problem in this code. What should your code actually return when there are no items returned? How can `.ToString()` return null? You can also just short-circuit it and return from function to "stop processing". Or may be it is better to throw an exception? Also, do not use string concatenation to builld SQL queries, it is subject to SQL injections.

Comment: You're also calling `Read()` twice in a row, throwing the first record away.

Comment: it just was a suggestion... the exact error is seen in line: 
key_id = String.Format(readerKey[0].ToString());

and exact error is:
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.'

I am trying to validate it to make sure this error is not thrown

Comment: _"Then ...(key_id) is not declared value"_ - No it's not. It says "unassigned". You can just initialize it explicitly ( `string key_id = string.Empty;` ) to overcome that error but be sure to check if it actually has been set to a valid value before using it.

Comment: BTW when you are only returning a single value .ExecuteScalar() is the easiest/most efficient way to do it, no need for a reader at all.  Your SqlCommand should be in a using() block also.

Comment: You should check the return value of readerKey.Read(). If it return false, there is no (more) data. If you ignore it and it was false and you try to access readerKey[0] it will throw seen exception. And of course Alex has a point there. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2 for reference.

Comment: @Fildor That's exactly what's happening. `readerkey.Read()` is displaying `false` value because there is no more data to select from. I am actually trying to bypass this by if statement to stop processing of readerKey.Read() value is set to false.

Comment: So just do `if( readerKey.Read()) { key_id = String.Format(readerKey[0].ToString()); }` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Fildor your solution works which shows another example where answer is just round the corner... Alex K. Thanks for good point I will read and investigate possible easier solutions.

Answer (score 0):

All you need do is assign *something* to key_id when you declare it, like:

```
string key_id = null; // not string key_id;
```

and later, after the using:

```
if (key_id != null)
{
    SelectSkuNumber(key_id); //---> Then ...(key_id) is not declared value
}
return key_id;
```

The caller of the function should, of course, know what to do if a null is returned.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that particular problem, you can assign some value or n`null` to `key_id`, eg. `key_id = "";`.

But you have some more problem there:

1. You are prone to SQL injection, you should use `Parameters` collection of `SqlCommand` class.
2. Are you sure you are concatenating your query correctly? Let's suppose

   ```
   newList = {"some", "thing"};
   ```

Then your query would be:

```
select top 1 KEY_NUMBER 
from MyTable where QTY_ON_HAND > 0
some
thing
order by NEWID()
```

Which is very, very incorrect to say the least.

3. `if(readerkey.Read().ToString() == null)` condition... `Read` returns `bool`, which is either `true` or `false`, it isn't reference type, so `ToString()` will never be `null`, thus the condition will always fail. If you want to check if there was `NULL` in database you should check:

   ```
   if (readerKey.Read() && readerKey["KEY_NUMBER"] == DBNull.Value)
   ```

which first read row, then receives value of column in that row. It uses short-circuiting for the case, where no records are returned.

4. `readerKey.Read();` is unnecessary before the `if` statement.